# What's up with Church?

Tags: mortal-instruments, shadowhunters, infernal-devices

Like, is he the same cat as in the Infernal Devices, or a descendant? And if he is the same, then how? Did living with a warlock do something to him, or did Magnus make him that way?

Answer (score 2):

It's the same cat. He was originally made immortal by Mrs. Dark at an unspecified time and was going to be used as part of the ritual to revive Mrs. Black. He was rescued by Jem and brought back to the London Institute. After Jem was made a Silent Brother, Magnus took him to New York. At some point, probably relatively soon after, Church ended up at the New York Institute, probably because Magnus traveled a lot and couldn't take care of him. Church, as an immortal cat, would attract notice by not dying after a while, making the New York Institute the best place for him.